# Microsoft keyboard.prefpane missing on my mac

Tags: mac

My Microsoft Sculpt Keyboard's function keys don't work.
All tutorials say that I should have `Microsoft keyboard.prefpane` in my  `/Library/PreferencePanes/` it's not there. And I can't find it in my mac elsewhere either.Also I can't see it on Microsoft page. Any idea how to get it?

Answer (score -1):

Aware this is an old question, but I found the IntelliType driver installer for anyone who (like me) is looking for this.

EDIT: This is for the Microsoft Natural Ergonomic 4000, but it will install IntelliType to use for Mac.

Download from Microsoft here: https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/keyboards/natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000/b2m-00012#techspecs-connect

Comment: Welcome to Super User. How does installing the IntelliType driver help?  Please [edit] your post to explain, rather than leave others to assume anything.

Comment: The question is about a problem on Mac with Microsoft hardware (and possibly some driver for Mac). Not about a Windows driver

Comment: Sorry, wrongly assumed there was Mac drivers for both. I've updated my answer.